# Help to understand: "leaders as diverse, patriotic, and big-hearted as the America…"

Tags: comparison, as, metaphors

In a tweet, Barack Obama wrote

> Today I’m proud to endorse such a wide and impressive array of Democratic candidates – **leaders as diverse, patriotic, and big-hearted as the America** they’re running to represent

I saw the sentence on [Yahoo! News](https://www.yahoo.com/news/obama-endorses-81-candidates-13-states-november-vote-171149878--politics.html).

*Leaders* are persons and *the America* refers to the country *the United States of America*. I am confused, how come we can draw a comparison like that? Any thoughts?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/81055/discussion-on-question-by-dan-help-to-understand-leaders-as-diverse-patriotic). It may be that this passage has other interesting aspects to it - in that case it should be posted as a new question and not asked and answered under this question.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The phrase **the America** there refers to its people, not to the land mass.

It is a synonym for **the citizenry (of America)**.

Comment: The technical term for this is [Synecdoche](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Synecdoche). A common U.S. example is to say "the White house did such-and-such" - the house, of course, just sat there like the inanimate object it is; the *occupants* (the President and other members of the executive branch who work in the White House) are the ones doing something.

Answer (score 14):

It means that the Democratic candidates show the same characteristics as the country they want to represent: the U.S.A.

That is, the U.S.A is a patriotic, big-hearted and diverse country in the same way as the Democratic candidates are.

Comment: I can understand a country can be *big-hearted and diverse*, but *patriotic* doesn't make much sense. Usually, it should be a person is patriotic.

Comment: @dan it's metaphorical. If you can understand how a continent, which is just a large piece of territory, can have a "big heart" then by the same token it can also be "patriotic".

Comment: @dan - 
US news
***American patriotism is unique***  https://www.theguardian.com/commentisfree/2013/apr/19/us-patriotism-declining-americans-see-world

Comment: The name *America* can refer to the country (consisting of its territories).  More commonly and more likely, it can refer to the nation (consisting of its people).